# Get the page count

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

I am developing a website using Sitecore 6.5

One of the requirements is to display 5 most popular pages at the right corner.

For that, I think of using the function that Analytic reports used for Page count.

I would like to know whether it is possible to do so by using Analytics API `Sitecore.Analytics`

If so, can I have some code snippets to do it as I am totally lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it in DMS:

```
private const string CommandText = "\r\nSELECT \r\ncount(distinct {0}VisitId{1})\r\n FROM {0}Pages{1}\r\n WHERE {0}ItemId{1} = {2}YourItemId{3}";

public static int GetPageViews(ID pageId)
{
  return DataAdapterManager.Provider.Sql.ReadOne<int>(CommandText, ReadPageViews, new object[] { "YourItemId", pageId.ToString() });
}

private static int ReadPageViews(DataProviderReader reader)
{
  return DataAdapterManager.Provider.Sql.GetInt(0, reader);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.. it works to get the current page count. Can I have a reference as I need to change that code into get all items with counts higher to lower.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is already answered, but why not use the PageDataTable directly to query? I made something like this:

```
 public static Dictionary<Item, int> GetVisitsCountForItem(Item item)
    {
        Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataSets.VisitorDataSet.PagesDataTable pagesDataTable = new VisitorDataSet.PagesDataTable();
        var pageViews = pagesDataTable.Select(p => p.ItemId == item.ID.Guid);
        var dic = new Dictionary<Item, int>();
        dic.Add(item, pageViews.Count());
        return dic;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the blog post "[Sitecore OMS data querying – Most viewed pages](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/09/mostviewedList.aspx)" which is written to get the most viewed pages for OMS (**not** DMS). This can at least give you a starting point, but you'd want to adjust the code to match the updated API.

Comment: Yes. it is a great topic but in 6.5 i can't find the session table in analytics database..